# 302 Found Response for google.com

Tags: httpresponse

I have a Java program which forwards the HTTP request from clients to INTERNET and write back the response to client. But  when clients trying Google.com from their browser i am getting 302 found Response from Internet.

Here is the Request from client :

```
GET http://google.com/ HTTP/1.1
Host: google.com
Proxy-Connection: keep-alive
Cache-Control: max-age=0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2272.118 Safari/537.36 OPR/28.0.1750.51
DNT: 1
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, lzma, sdch
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
Cookie: PREF=ID=0168c274e46046ff:FF=0:LD=en:TM=1427909641:LM=1428321915:GM=1:S=HGTpo1ahuPUd4Nu2; SID=DQAAAPgAAACOH1NUVCRnVJfjL-W4MtbTmqx9yY1Wbra4LM7D8_uslXU_43zD4QrZl4eHqBuukNoKFw0gD68Vt7DltSgBrOoVRufDgeLImP8321g2-IxjmtqwjJoI9sSM3YEwC5ZvnTNyrwuHhBp-zZqImsaHshVmvt8GEV1WDFHs4OZ74g219CeKYztHKjsQLDS_yZ725qsIKWjvbb_NlnO5IqktZ0Q6JXIMRPzshZQvoq7ZiwH9RfiIASpHIiFC1XDwrMZDcbONpKCke2QxZtmxSPfUHXuBx53bJOZFHUrcAJAvihBAXoFwZHUr2beVtRuLe1w8blbt6AGTy9dT9gZ9nVjeSHzK; HSID=Aso16-EnwP4siCr5Q; APISID=DIHL_mSdprkZSELD/AjGWXXsjCWUT9FEuy; NID=67=DGyWJrkoHYqgDmpEMmQVlnzZQLlwGNTxbAZ8--PQeTPlZ4SbL3AbFNP40h0NOI3ztb_6SkDTHwGJonmESsToDR6Vkmur0VST-6k34xVvQM9FQH_PaoMrK8O6kT0Avd8FIITl7G7ERJbvbwWIsCuhIwZOR2cj2r6aCmnM27A
```

This is the Response i got :

```
HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Cache-Control: private
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Location: http://www.google.co.in/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=Uhw7Vbe6H_PI8Ae_qICIBA
Content-Length: 261
Date: Sat, 25 Apr 2015 04:47:14 GMT
Server: GFE/2.0
Alternate-Protocol: 80:quic,p=1

<HTML><HEAD><meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">
<TITLE>302 Moved</TITLE></HEAD><BODY>
<H1>302 Moved</H1>
The document has moved
<A HREF="http://www.google.co.in/?gfe_rd=cr&amp;ei=Uhw7Vbe6H_PI8Ae_qICIBA">here</A>.
</BODY></HTML>
```

Is this because Google using HTTPS instead of HTTP. and it is trying to redirect the request...?

But *how i should process this reply?*
I send the same response to client. But *no redirection is happening,
What should i do?*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the `Location` header in the Http Response, seems that Google detected that the call came from India and it's redirecting the call to Google India i.e. `http://www.google.co.in/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=Uhw7Vbe6H_PI8Ae_qICIBA`.

When you get a 302 response your client should react properly and follow the call to the `Location` header.

Comment: Thanks!. ? I send the same response to the client. But no redirection is happening.That means no further request is coming from client..What could be the reason..?

Comment: What browser are they using? Also do you do any manipulation to the http response in Java before sending it to the browser (e.g changing the http status code)?

Comment: Clients are trying from different browsers.But all they are getting the same Result. I manually typed the redirecting URL               http://www.google.co.in/?gfe_rd=cr&amp;ei=Uhw7Vbe6H_PI8Ae_qICIBA           in one of the client browser. then i got another Response

Comment: This was the response  :TTP/1.1 302 Found
Location: https://www.google.co.in/?gfe_rd=cr&amp;ei=mic7VeykHOHI8AeQhoHoAQ&gws_rd=ssl
Cache-Control: private
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Date: Sat, 25 Apr 2015 05:36:54 GMT
Server: gws
Content-Length: 281
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
Alternate-Protocol: 80:quic,p=1

Comment: <HTML><HEAD><meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">
<TITLE>302 Moved</TITLE></HEAD><BODY>
<H1>302 Moved</H1>
The document has moved
<A HREF="https://www.google.co.in/?gfe_rd=cr&amp;amp;ei=mic7VeykHOHI8AeQhoHoAQ&amp;gws_rd=ssl">here</A>.
</BODY></HTML>

Comment: This is quite interesting just tested from the a chrome browser seems that the query parameters will do the difference. When a tried (google.co.in/?gfe_rd=cr&amp;ei=Uhw7Vbe6H_PI8Ae_qICIBA) I was redirected to Google.com, then I tried without them I was able to check Google India, can you try typing manually just `google.co.in` ?

Comment: Request from client :CONNECT www.google.co.in:443 HTTP/1.1
Host: www.google.co.in
Proxy-Connection: keep-alive
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2272.118 Safari/537.36 OPR/28.0.1750.51

Comment: Response :    HTTP/1.1 405 Method Not Allowed
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Content-Length: 1456
Date: Sat, 25 Apr 2015 05:57:51 GMT
Server: GFE/2.0
Alternate-Protocol: 80:quic,p=1
Connection: close

Comment: Yeah last thing is enforcing SSL, hence the connect to port `443`, what is not clear is the 405 `Method Not Allowed ` response, `https://google.co.in` supports the `GET` operation you're trying, does the java client tries another method?

Comment: how this ssl problem can be solved?
I think the 405 method not allowed due to the CONNECT method

Answer (score -1):

Sometimes it is an issue about ipv6 transaction against ipv4.

Try **disable ipv6** in your server and **reboot** with:

```
echo net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6=1 > /etc/sysctl.d/disableipv6.conf
```